# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, ssl

I am trying to make a request to a server which is https but does not have `SSL`.

I tried to ignore ssl Certificate verification in my code below :

```
func loadInfoAny(parameters: parameters, url: "https://domain/WebApiMobileGateway/api/MobileGatewayApi/PreActivation", completionHandler:@escaping (Bool, [[String: Any]]?) -> ()) {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]


    let sessionManager = SessionManager()
    sessionManager.delegate.taskDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion = { (_, _, challenge, completionHandler) -> Void in
        // Pass test server with self signed certificate
        if challenge.protectionSpace.host == url {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        } else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }

    sessionManager.request(url, method:.post, parameters: parameters, headers : headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case let .success(value):

                 print(value)

            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
                completionHandler(false, nil)
            }
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://domain/WebApiMobileGateway/api/MobileGatewayApi/PreActivation, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://domain/WebApiMobileGateway/api/MobileGatewayApi/PreActivation}.

I've tried adding the domain to my `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `Info.plist` but that did not work. Turning on `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are comparing the host with the url.

Change condition as follows

```
 if challenge.protectionSpace.host == "41.230.10.77" {
     completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
 } else {
     completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
 }
```